# What does this info mean when installing git from source?

Tags: git, centos7

I am installing git from source according to documentation on centos 7.2,https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git

The error info is as follow:
[image]

What does this error info mean?

Answer (score 1):

You have to [enable the EPEL repository](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL#How_can_I_use_these_extra_packages.3F) and install the missing  package which git depends upon:

```
sudo yum install docbook2X
```